# signaturepad is not working when scrollview is enabled in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin.forms.
I am using SignaturePad.Xamarin.Forms.PCL for signature pad. This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:acr="clr-namespace:Acr.XamForms.SignaturePad;assembly=Acr.XamForms.SignaturePad"
             x:Class="App4.newpage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout>
                <Button Text="button1"/>
                <Button Text="button2"/>
                <Button Text="button3"/>
                <Button Text="button4"/>
                <Button Text="button5"/>
                <Button Text="button6"/>
                <Button Text="button7"/>
                <Button Text="button8"/>

                <acr:SignaturePadView
                x:Name="padView"
                HeightRequest="320"
                WidthRequest="240"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                CaptionText="Caption This"
                CaptionTextColor="Black"
                ClearText="Clear Me!"
                ClearTextColor="Red"
                PromptText="Prompt Here"
                PromptTextColor="Red"
                SignatureLineColor="Aqua"
                StrokeColor="Black"
                StrokeWidth="2" 
            />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I cant work on signaturepad because of scrollview is used.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only obvious answer here is: don't put it in a `ScrollView`. I can imagine that the UI can't tell apart if you want to scroll or draw a line.

Even if you get it to work, I don't think the user-experience will be great. What happens if the user has a smaller type of device, the signature control takes up the full screen, how are you going to scroll out of there at that point?

Of course, I have no clue what your requirements are, but maybe you can add a button that takes you to a new screen to add the signature?

Comment: yes, you are correct Gerald. Finally i am using popup menu for this issue.